# Shell - Sed REGEXP capture from a word till an eventual comma and the end of line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am struggling with regex using sed
I am reading a file with lines

```
word1 word2 myword word4 word5 word6,
lorem ipsum dolor amet myword asinus es 
salut comment ca va myword c'est comme ca,
```

I want to get

```
word1 word2,
lorem ipsum dolor amet
salut comment ca va,
```

This is only a portion of my file, that's why I need to work only line by line.
All I could find was :

```
echo $line | sed -e 's/\(myword.*\)\(,\)$/\2/g'
```

But I only get

```
word1 word2,
lorem ipsum dolor amet myword asinus es 
salut comment ca va,
```

I cannot capture if there is a last comma or not. Can anyone help me ?

The question is more : I want to get everything before "myword" and keep the last comma if I have one using sed regexp

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get everything before "myword" (in which case why the commas?) or everything after myword (in which case why only 3 "blas" on output line 1) or the last 3 fields on each line or something else? Please update your sample input, expected output and description to clarify.

Comment: I want to get everything before "myword" and keep the last comma if I have one using sed regexp

Comment: You just updated the question.  Could you have a look at your expected output?  It seems inconsistent -- 2 lines contain `myword` and one doesn't.  Better explain that?

Comment: Sorry, ok now after editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a label.  Check if the line ends in a comma and act accordingly:

```
sed -e '/,$/{s/\( myword.*\)\(,\)$/\2/; ba}' -e 's/\( myword.*\)//' -e :a inputfile
```

For your input, produces:

```
bla bla bla,
ble ble ble
blo blo blo,
```

Comment: @devnull ==> Yes! that's the answer. thank you so much !
@ Rahul ==> I tried your solution, but it did not work :(

Comment: If you're using anything other than s, g, and p (with -n) in sed then either you're using the wrong tool or there's a simpler sed solution. All other sed language constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of everything from " myword" up to a comma or end of line:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\) myword[^,]*/\1/' file
word1 word2,
lorem ipsum dolor amet
salut comment ca va,
```

Comment: +1 totally agree with your thoughts on `sed`. Using branches and buffers just lead to obfuscated and unmaintainable code. Though secretly I do love occasional challenges to solve a complex problem in `sed` but is never my preferred tool for anything other than substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ myword[^,]*//' file
```

Which deletes from the first space before `myword` to the first following `,` or end of line, or:

```
sed 's/ myword.*\([^,]\|\(,\)\)$/\2/' file
```

Which deletes from the first space before `myword` to the end of line or the `,` before the end of line.