# sed command to delete text until match is found for each line of a csv

Tags: regex, linux, csv, sed, data-manipulation

I have a csv file and I am trying to delete all characters from the beginning of the line till it finds the first occurrence of "2015". I want to do this for each line in the csv file.

My csv file structure is as follows:

```
Field1 , Field2 , Field3 , Field4
sometext1 , 2015-07-15 , sometext2, sometext3
sometext1 , 2015-07-14 , sometext2, sometext3
sometext1 , 2015-07-13 , sometext2, sometext3
```

I cannot use the cut command or sed for the first occurrence of a comma because the text in the Field1 sometimes has commas in them too, which is making it complicated for parsing. I figured if I search for the first occurrence of the text 2015 for each line and replace all the preceding characters with nothing, then that should work.

FYI I only want to do this for the FIRST occurrence of 2015 only. There is another text field with 2015 in it within another column and I don't any text prior to that to be affected.

For example, if my original line is:

```
sometext1,#015,2015-07-10,sometext2,2015,sometext3
```

I want it to return:

```
2015-07-10,sometext2,2015,sometext3
```

Does anyone know the sed command to do this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: _"the text in the Field1 sometimes has commas in them too,"_  In that case, show us a useful example of your input file.  Are those commas escaped or quoted or what?

Comment: Instead of `sed`, consider one of [these options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063125/linux-tool-to-parse-csv-files).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell - Sed REGEXP capture from a word till an eventual comma and the end of line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717709/shell-sed-regexp-capture-from-a-word-till-an-eventual-comma-and-the-end-of-lin)

Comment: Not sed but `perl -lne 's/^.*?2015//g;print"2015$_"' file`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with sed assuming "#####" never occurs in a line:

```
sed -e 's/2015/#####&/'|sed -e 's/.*#####//'
```

For example:

```
> echo sometext1,#015,2015-07-10,sometext2,2015,sometext3\
  |sed -e 's/2015/#####&/'|sed -e 's/.*#####//'
2015-07-10,sometext2,2015,sometext3
```

The first sed command prefixes "#####" to the first occurence of 2015 and the second sed command removes everything from the beginning to the end of the "#####" prefix.

The basic reason for using this two stage method is that sed's regular expression matcher has only greedy wildcards that always pick the longest match and does not support lazy matching which picks the shortest match.

If "#####" may occur in a line a more unlikely string could be substituted for it such as "7z#dNjm_wG8a3!esu@Rhv=".

Comment: You can do it with one `sed` invocation: `sed -e 's/2015/#####&/' -e 's/.*#####//'` which is neater and tidier.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with `sed` without Perl-style non-greedy operators, you need to mark the first instance with something you know won't be in the line, as Tris describes.  However, that solution requires knowledge of what **won't** be in the file.  Fortunately, you can guarantee that a newline won't be in the line because that's what **terminated** the line.  Thus you can do something like:

```
sed 's/2015/\n&/;s/.*\n//' input.txt > output.txt
```

NOTE: this won't modify the header row which you would have to treat specially.

Comment: new line is never in a line read by sed unless very specific sed option on GNU sed, good ans simple solution